# Start application in the background on GNOME

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, programming, c++

Is there a way to avoid bringing an application to the front when opening it? I'm launching an app several times trough a terminal window (running a custom c++ program) and it keeps popping up when opening.

Answer (score 0):

try `gtk.gdk.Window.lower` in https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/2.24/class-gdkwindow.html. There will be equivalent functions in other toolkits too.